# Flutter - SharedPreferences saving list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have an app that is connected to Firebase, and I am making a screen that will show all notifications sent, for that I am using SharedPreferences. But as the notification arrives on a map, I am placing it inside a List <Map <dynamic, dynamic >>, to show the notification.

```
      String title, body;
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> notific;
      List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> notifList = [];
///Widget
    return Scaffold(
          extendBody: true,
          backgroundColor: widget._colors.white,
          appBar: appBar,
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: notifList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                elevation: 4,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    notifList.elementAt(i)['title'],
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    notifList.elementAt(i)['body'],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
```

Firebase Method

```
  Future<dynamic> fcmMessageReceiver() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((value) {
      if (value != null) {}
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (message.notification != null) {
        notific = {
          'title': message.notification.title,
          'body': message.notification.body
        };
        notifList.add(notific);
        setState(() {
          title = message.notification.title;
          body = message.notification.body;
        });
        print('MENSAGEM: $notific');
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {});
  }
```

Shared Preferences method, being called on initState()

```
  void savePush() async {
    SharedPreferences sharePref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final strList = sharePref.getStringList('push')??[];
    sharePref.setStringList('push', notifList.toString());
  }
```

My question is, how can I keep these notifications, so whenever I want to see them, I can get them easily, and set up the Cards with the notifications?

Comment: So, basically what you want is to save the List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> in the SharedPreferences, right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do this. I need to save the list, so that later it will show notifications on the Scaffold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are many approaches to solve this issue, some of my approaches will be to convert each message to a `JSON encoded string` and then push it to the `sharedPreference.setStringList(list)`. Another way is to make the whole list a `JSON encoded string` and save it to `SharedPreferences` like a string by calling `sharedPreference.setString(list)`.

---

Let's say your List of the message is like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> messagesForUI = [];
```

And, you've initialized `SharedPreferences` and previous messages from `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
List<String> sharedPreferenceMessages = [];
```

Now, to retrieve all your previous messages from `SharedPreferences` and then set the previous messages to `messagesForUI` inside the `initState` method, you can do this:

```
sharedPreferenceMessages = sharedPreference.getStringList("messages") ?? [];
sharedPreferenceMessages.forEach((element) {
  Map<String, dynamic> messageMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(element));
  messagesForUI.add(messageMap);
});
```

Now, you've your list ready to roll.

Let's say you have a new message from FCM and you want to save it to the `SharedPreferences`. Let's save the new message this way:

```
Map<String, dynamic> newMessage = Map<String, dynamic>.from(fcmMessage);

setState((){
  messagesForUI.add(newMessage);
});

String newMessageJson = json.encode(newMessage);
sharedPreferenceMessages.add(newMessageJson);
sharedPreference.setStringList("messages", sharedPreferenceMessages);
```

There you go. You can also save messages to `SharedPreferences` via calling `sharedPreference.setString(map)`, just like this approach. If need a demonstration of that process, just comment here.

Sample code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class NotificationRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotificationRouteState createState() => _NotificationRouteState();
}

class _NotificationRouteState extends State<NotificationRoute> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> messagesForUI = [];
  List<String> sharedPreferenceMessages = [];
  SharedPreferences sharedPreference;

  @override
  void initState() {
    init();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: messagesForUI.isEmpty
          ? Center(
              child: Text("No notifications"),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final Map<String, dynamic> message = messagesForUI[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(message["title"]),
                  subtitle: Text(message["body"]),
                );
              },
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: messagesForUI.length,
            ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Map<String, dynamic> newMessage = {"title": "test title", "body": "test body"};

          setState(() {
            messagesForUI.add(newMessage);
          });

          String newMessageJson = json.encode(newMessage);
          sharedPreferenceMessages.add(newMessageJson);
          sharedPreference.setStringList("messages", sharedPreferenceMessages);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  init() async {
    sharedPreference = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferenceMessages = sharedPreference.getStringList("messages") ?? [];
    sharedPreferenceMessages.forEach((element) {
      Map<String, dynamic> messageMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(element));
      messagesForUI.add(messageMap);
    });
  }
}
```

Now, as I don't have any `FCM` set-up on my project, I just replicate the message add process to the `SharedPreference` via `FloatingActionButton`.

Happy coding :D

Comment: Apparently it didn't work. When you exit and re-enter the screen, notifications disappear. Should I keep calling it, in the Text () widget? `notifList.elementAt (i) ['title']`

Comment: did you initialize messagesForUI from SharedPreferences in the initState method? I'm assuming that you're using a StatefulWidget widget

Comment: I'm using Statefull yes, but it's currently inside the class and not the method, because I'm calling messagesForUI in the scaffold widget, to show the new and old notifications from firebase.

Comment: bro, I understand you're calling messagesForUI in the scaffold widget. But look deeply, your StatefulWidget widget has initState method, build method and destory method. You're returning scaffold widget inside build method, which is correct. But you have to set the messagesForUI variable inside initState method. In this way, whenever you enter the screen, your messagesForUI list will be updated all the time.

Comment: But how am I going to call the variable in the scaffold? I'm new to Flutter, I still get lost very easily with state methods.

Comment: I've added a sample code for you. check the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231139/discussion-between-omar-khaium-chowdhury-and-kaya-ryuuna).

Comment: Ok, I will be there